# Getting errors in java when attempting to loop over a loop

Tags: java

This is the error message i'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextBoolean(Scanner.java:1893)
    at calcSums.main(calcSums.java:24)
```

---

This is my code:

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calcSums
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
     calcSum:{
         Boolean again = Boolean.valueOf("y");
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
      double number;
      double sum = 0;
      System.out.println("Enter a positive number");
      number = keyboard.nextDouble();
      while (number > 0)
      {
       sum = sum + number;
       System.out.println("Enter another positive number, enter 0 or negative to end");
       number = keyboard.nextDouble();
   
      }
      System.out.println("The sum is: ");
      System.out.println(sum);
         System.out.println("Would you like to find another sum? (y/n)");
         again = keyboard.nextBoolean();
         if (again.equals("y"))  {
         break calcSum; }
     }
 }
}
```

I was getting error messages before about how i was implementing my if statement since i didn't use the .equals and when it allowed me to run through the code I thought I was done, then when I tried to loop over the block again it gave me the error messages

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: In my programming class we were messing around with java, we made a program that found the sum of numbers until the user typed 0 or negative. I wanted to make it so that when they were finished and got their answer it would ask if they wanted to do another sum calculation. I wanted to do this because i didn't want to have to compile and run the same program over and over again just to work out any bugs

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can't enter 'y' as a Boolean. The String representation of a Boolean is "true" or "false".
Just change your again-Variable in a String like this:

```
String again = new String();
... //Your other code
System.out.println("Would you like to find another sum? (y/n)");
again = keyboard.nextLine();
if (again.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))  {
    break calcSum; 
}
```

And also think about using another while loop instead of your calcsum-label.

```
String again = new String("y");
while(again.equalsIgnoreCase("y"){
   ... //Your other code

    System.out.println("Would you like to find another sum? (y/n)");
    //again = keyboard.nextLine();
    again = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try this, i've been thinking of ways to implement the break in a different way and I was thinking about the same thing as you I just had no idea how to do it, i've only ever done web page programming before this

Comment: Right now i'm using a school provided chromebook and an online java compiler, i'm gonna wait till i get back to the lab to test it

Comment: I've just tried to use it and after it asks for yes or no it pauses the program rather than waiting for user input

Comment: It seems that keyboard.nextLine() was always returning an empty String. I don't know why. I edited the Post and replaced the last Line with a working Version. Please try this